# Why does Play's PushEnumerator need to close() before the iterator will complete?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

The following example, adapted from the Play Framework's documentation:

```
val enumerateUsers: Enumerator[String] = {
  Enumerator("Guillaume", "Sadek", "Peter", "Erwan")
}
val consumeOne = Cont[String, String](in =>
  in match {
    case Input.EOF =>
      Done("", Input.Empty)
    case Input.Empty =>
      Done("", Input.Empty)
    case Input.El(s) =>
      Done(s, Input.Empty)
  })
println((enumerateUsers |>> consumeOne).flatMap(_.run).await.get)
```

prints out `Guillaume`.

However, if I change it so that the `Enumerator` is a `PushEnumerator`:

```
val enumerateUsers: PushEnumerator[String] = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
// consumeOne as before
val i = enumerateUsers |>> consumeOne
enumerateUsers.push("Guillaume")
enumerateUsers.push("Sadek")
enumerateUsers.push("Peter")
enumerateUsers.push("Erwan")
println(i.flatMap(_.run).await.get)
// Timeout exception
```

I get a timeout exception on the iteratee's promise.

In order to get it to do the same as before, I need to close the `PushEnumerator`.

```
val enumerateUsers: PushEnumerator[String] = Enumerator.imperative[String]()
// consumeOne as before
val i = enumerateUsers |>> consumeOne
enumerateUsers.push("Guillaume")
enumerateUsers.push("Sadek")
enumerateUsers.push("Peter")
enumerateUsers.push("Erwan")
enumerateUsers.close() // <-- magic line
println(i.flatMap(_.run).await.get)
```

And this prints `Guillaume` as before.

I can't find the doc that tells me why, or what the semantic difference is here.  Can someone please point the way?

**Edit**: I've found my answer in the Play source - it took some hunting :)  I'll mark @huynhjl's answer as correct since he sort of answered it, but the specific answer that I was looking for is pretty simple.  The Play implementation uses a side-effect to drive the socket, which isn't unreasonable - it's just not what I had assumed (assumptions kill everything :D).  Inside `play.core.server.netty.Helpers` there is a function called `socketOut[A](...)`.  `socketOut[A](...)` has function called `step`, which returns an Iteratee.  This Iteratee writes `e` to the output channel when the input case matches `El(e)`.  My assumption was that Iteratees could partially consume Enumerators from which you could get a value, but it would seem that the only way to may that happen is via a side effect... I think :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role of the `Enumerator` object is to feed the elements to the iteratee in a specific order until there are no more elements or until the iteratee is done and then return that iteratee. The `close()` call indicates when there is no more input so that the iteratee result can be returned. Without calling *close* it's possible there would still be more to push. So I haven't tried but I expect that this would be equivalent to your example:

```
val i = enumerateUsers |>> consumeOne
i.flatMap(_.run).onRedeem(println) // we will have a result we want to print
// now feed some data
enumerateUsers.push("Guillaume")
enumerateUsers.push("Sadek")
enumerateUsers.push("Peter")
enumerateUsers.push("Erwan")
// no more input, trigger promise computation
enumerateUsers.close()
```

It is more meaningful if you apply `enumerateUsers` to an iteratee where you cannot tell ahead of time how many elements it needs to get a result (the general case).

Comment: I'll have to try and dig in to the Play source because it's not clear to me how this is supposed to work with `WebSocket`s.  As far as I recall (I'm not at the right terminal ATM) I keep `push`ing to the outbound enumerator on the WebSocket.  I don't need to `close` it to get it to produce stuff on wire, yet each `push` seems to produce.  If that's the case, then there's some mechanism I'm missing.

Comment: @DerekWyatt, technically WebSocket may not have to extract the result of the iteratee as long as the elements are being pushed. So may be that's why it's not necessary.

Comment: Added my findings to the end of my question.