# Why does PushEnumerator hang here?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, loops

In an sbt play project I run `console-project` and paste in this code:

```
import play.api.libs.iteratee._

val e = Enumerator.imperative[String]()

e.push("foo")
e.push("bar")
e.push("bah")
e.close

val i: Iteratee[String, String] = Iteratee.consume[String]()

val applied = (e andThen Enumerator.eof) |>> i

Iteratee.flatten(applied).run.value.get
```

However it dies with a timeout.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Here is one relevant.But I still get TIMEOUT.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641294/why-does-plays-pushenumerator-need-to-close-before-the-iterator-will-complete

Comment: Yeah, I believe the distinction is that I push and close into my enumerator before applying it to the Iteratee, but I see nothing that indicates that this should be a problem in the documentation.

Comment: No, it matters. You can look at the source code of Enumerator.scala at https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/iteratees/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/iteratee/Enumerator.scala. When no iteratee applied, push does nothing and return false because there's no some kind of internal storage for what you've pushed.